# Best iphone backup tool for enterprise

Tags: windows, backup

Looking for a program that will backup up and deploy backups to Iphones, have roughly 50-60 Iphones which need to be backed up and rolled out across 3 days.

Looking for something simple if possible.

Running windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: Free or paid?...

Comment: Either will do, just looking for something efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a free solution check out [synciso](http://www.syncios.com/backup-iphone-without-itunes-for-free.html), it does not require itunes or icloud to back your data up to Windows, it has a nice UI and a detailed tutorial on its site.

If ease of use is the number one factor for you look at [iskysoft](https://www.iskysoft.com/phone-transfer/), it has one-click back up, however it is $39.95 (with free trial).

Here are a few others, if they are not what you want:

https://imazing.com/

http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/

http://www.copytrans.net/shelbee/

These seem to be the best ones, hopefully one will be what you are looking for.